# Push Notification Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I've just added push notifications to my app and have tested it just fine with a development SSL. I have gotten a production SSL. My question is, do I need to do anything with my provisioning profile, like create a new one or just continue to use the current one?

Comment: You need to use a production certificate before launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to download provisioning profile again if you have configured your app for production SSL otherwise the changes you made will not be reflected.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Do I actually need to create a new profile or just download the existing one again?

Comment: Go to Organizer and then Provisioning Profiles in top left corner. Then delete existing provisioning you are using. And then download new provisioning from developer.apple.com and then install it in XCode.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same profile. You have to create a distribution provisioning profile. You can't download the existing profile.

[image]

When you create a provisioning profile you specify whether it's a development profile or a distribution profile :

[image]